# kWS Android web server can't open JSP files

Tags: android, jsp

I want to run an HTTP server on my Android phone. I am using kWS server to serve my files. Files with .html extension are running correctly like `index.html`. But I want to use dynamic pages with JSP. So when I put my JSP file to server homepage and open localhost from browser, kWS downloads JSP file instead of running. What should I do to have my server interpret JSP files?

Comment: kws web server does not support JSP as far as I can see from it's description.

Comment: kWS is written with Java. How it can't support JSP?

Comment: nowhere on the internet it is said that it supports it. Just google for `kws jsp`. This *likely* means that it does not support it